# How can simplify my regex

Tags: regex, url, routes

How could i to simplify my regex to get urls that contains:

```
de-[.+]
em-[.+]
empresa-[.+]
area-[.+]
```

in **any order**, for example

```
/home/de-xpto/area-xpto/empresa-xpto
```

or

```
/home/area-xpto/empresa-xpto/de-xpto
```

or

```
/home/empresa-xpto/em-xpto/de-xpto
```

etc...

And a regex too that can i identify if dont have any one of list.

```
\/home\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))\/([de|area|em|empresa]*-([^\/]+))
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [`^\/home(?:\/(?:de|em(?:presa)?|area)-[^\/]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/mX3oT6/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex contains character classes with `|` alternation symbol, which is wrong. You must use *grouping constructs* `(...)` to match alternative sequences of characters.

This said, you most probably need

```
\/home(?:\/(?:de|em(?:presa)?|area)-[^\/]+)+
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mX3oT6/3).

- `\/home` - matches `/home`
- `(?:\/(?:de|em(?:presa)?|area)-[^\/]+)+` - matches 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\/` - a `/` symbol
  - `(?:de|em(?:presa)?|area)` - either `de` or `em` or `empresa` or `area`
  - `-` - a literal `-`
  - `[^\/]+` - 1+ symbols other than `/`

If you need to match these URLs as full strings, add `^` (at the start) and `$` (at the end) anchors.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks. Could say me how i make this same regex, but now, thats does not contains the list? i tried to put ^ but dont works.

Comment: What do you mean by there is no list? There is no such a notion as a list in regex. There is a group of alternatives inside parentheses. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: for example: the regex match this: /home/de-xpto/em-xpto. now i want one to match if has one that doesnt not contains in list [de|em|empresa|etc]... example: /home/de-xpto/xpto/area-xpto

Comment: To match text not equal to some other text use the tempered greedy token like `(?:(?!de|em(?:persa)?).)*`